# I'm trying to create function, when somebody will send link on message, it will be deleted

Tags: python, discord.py

This is how it should work. If user sent link on message, it will be deleted. But if  member has special role, it won't be deleted. But it send this error:

```
line 154, in on_message
    if member.role.name == ('Test'):
NameError: name 'member' is not defineddefined
```

Please help me.

My code:

```
async def on_message(message):
  url= re.findall('https//')
  if member.role.name == ('Test'):
    return
  elif url and message.channel.id == "842466772568899648":
    await bot.delete_message(message)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have some mistakes in your code:

1. You don't use `member` in `on_message` event. Instead you use `message.author`
2. You can get a list of `role` objects, so the best way to check if user has a role is to use [List Comprehension](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_lists_comprehension.asp)
3. Every id is `int` not a `str` so you have to delete `"` from `"842466772568899648"`
4. `bot` has no method named `delete_message()` but `message` has method `delete()`

How it should look:

```py
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    if "Test" in [role.name for role in message.author.roles]:
        return
    if "https://" in message.content and message.channel.id == 842466772568899648:
        await message.delete()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check it with regular expressions. Also use message.author instead of member.

```
import re
REGEX = re.compile(r"https?://(?:www\.)?.+")

@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    if not message.author.bot:
        if REGEX.match(message.content):
            await ctx.send("Please don't use any links in this channel!")
```